# How to get multiple set-cookie from response

Tags: resttemplate

I have a web service call that returns two `Set-Cookie`s. From the response, I am only able to see/get one (the first one, weird. Shouldn't it be the last one?)

Using CURL

```
< Set-Cookie: lat=MTQ5MTMyOTE5MzYyNQ==;domain=my.company.com;path=/
< Set-Cookie: vid=some_random_text;domain=my.company.com;path=/;HttpOnly
```

My code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
...


MultiValueMap<String, String> payload = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
payload.add("_charset_", "UTF-8");
...

HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(payload, headers);


ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);

List<String> cookies = response.getHeaders().get("Set-Cookie");
```

Cookies only have the first cookie and length of one. I am trying to retrieve the second Set-Cookie value.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm having the same problem.